# Remove characters in pattern of words

Tags: text-processing

I have sentences with words that have a pattern such as `p.G345L` and `p.X31Z`. I need to remove `p.` so I get `G345L` and `X31Z`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you have delimiting this, but you can easily pipe this through sed. With the GNU implementation of `sed`, in the pattern matching '\b' will denote a word boundary, which you can use to make sure you don't pick up part of a sentence, such as "stop."

```
$ cat file
p.G345L sentence stop.  p.X31Z part of another sentence
$ sed 's/\bp\.//g' file 
G345L sentence stop.  X31Z part of another sentence
```

Comment: Those sentences could exist in many text file in a directory, i need the file(s) to be updated

Comment: @user2957777, use `sed -i` e.g. `sed -i ..... *.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

If the pattern is `p.` followed by an uppercase letter, followed by a sequence of one or more decimal digits followed by one uppercase letter, then that would be (POSIXly):

```
sed 's/p\.\([[:upper:]][[:digit:]]\{1,\}[[:upper:]]\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways.

With `perl`:

```
$ echo "p.G345L and p.X31Z" | perl -pe 's/p\.//g'
G345L and X31Z
```

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "p.G345L and p.X31Z" | sed 's/p\.//g'
G345L and X31Z
```